# Ignoring condition if the parameter is null in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am currently developing the search and filtering feature of my project. I am trying to retrieve data with this Request body:

```
{
    "researchers": [
        "Jhon Doe"
    ],
    "unit": null,
    "agency":null,
    "date": null,
    "status": null,
    "budget": null
}
```

and below is the method from the ReasearchRepository that retrieves this data:

```
    @Query("select r from Research r " +
            "left join r.fundingAgencies fundingAgencies " +
            "left join r.researchers researchers " +
            "where (:budgetStart is null or :budgetEnd is null or  r.budget between :budgetStart and :budgetEnd )" +
            "and (:startDate is null or r.startDate >= :startDate) " +
            "and (:endDate is null or r.endDate <= :endDate) " +
            "and (:agencyNames is null or fundingAgencies.agencyName in :agencyNames) " +
            "and (:unitNames is null or r.deliveryUnit.unitName in :unitNames )" +
            "and (:names is null or researchers.name in :names ) " +
            "and (:researchStatuses is null or r.researchStatus in :researchStatuses)")
    List<Research> findAdvanced( @Param("budgetStart") Double budgetStart,
                                 @Param("budgetEnd")  Double budgetEnd,
                                 @Param("startDate")  LocalDate startDate,
                                 @Param("endDate") LocalDate endDate,
                                 @Param("agencyNames") Collection<String> agencyNames,
                                 @Param("unitNames") Collection<String> unitNames,
                                 @Param("names") Collection<String> names,
                                 @Param("researchStatuses") Collection<ResearchStatus> researchStatuses);
```

My problem is when I'm trying to find data from given values in the request, it returns an empty list **[]** even though it exists in the database. What I want to achieve is that if the parameter is null, it will ignore a specific condition in the query and will still return data.

I just followed the article from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters).

I also find another article about using Criteria API, but it will take a lot of time for me to understand that. My project is a bit rush.

TIA

Comment: you can go with `JDBCTemplate`, build the query based on non-null values

Comment: Is it okay if I integrate it with my project that has Spring Data Jpa?

Comment: This ":paramName is null" code looks correct, you did well following www.baeldung.com article. I think your problem is not in these null conditions.

Comment: It is working now. I just found out that there is something wrong with my Service class. There is a procedure in my codes that modifies the data. Anyways, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems like a good case to use Specifications.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/